# Update the table of a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database containing this table:
[image: Table]

The table is made up of 3 columns:
-id :identify each row of the table
-address: keep all the addresses
-default: a Boolean column where `1` defines the default address used by the user

**On the image above the default address used is `address1`**

I would like to add a fourth address and set that fourth address to default. So I wrote the following lines:

```
-UPDATE address SET default=false
-INSERT INTO addresses SET address = `address4`, default=true
```

What I would like to know is that, is there any way to combine the 2 lines to improve performance?
Or using the 2 lines is ok ?

Thanks in advance for providing your help

Comment: Two lines is okay.  Update modifies and existing record.  Insert creates a new one. Different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot combine them into a single statement.  You can, however, combine them into a single transaction so they take effect at the same time.

You do this with `start transaction`, which is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).

Also, I would suggest that you reverse the operations:

```
INSERT INTO addresses
    SET address = $address4,
        default = false;

UPDATE address
    SET default = (case when address = $address4" then true else false end);
```

This looks more complicated.  But, if you are not using transactions ensures that the default address is always set for other processes querying the table (assuming the storage engine has some ACID capabilities).

Comment: Thanks for providing your help